# Axios - display the full API endpoint for troubleshooting

Tags: api, axios

I created a simple Api to GET a list if objects. When I run my project locally, the endpoint is https://localhost:7290/api/Transactions/GetFailedTransactions

I have tested the above endpoint in Postman without issue.
The controller code is as follows :-

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TransactionsController : Controller
{
    private ITransactionService _service;
    public TransactionsController(ITransactionService service_)
    {
        this._service = service_;
    }

    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IActionResult GetFailedTransactions()
    {
        var allTransactions = _service.GetFailedTransactions();
        return Ok(allTransactions);
    }
 }
```

The 'Issue' arises when I use axios to make the GET request to afore mentioned API.

My react component  is running the following code. The error handling kicks in and shows a response status of 404. The Error data contains the following message 'Cannot GET /api/Transactions/GetFailedTransactions'
**Question : How do I display the FULL endpoint being called? I suspect that I am not calling the endpoint that Postman is referencing.**

```js
axios.get("api/Transactions/GetFailedTransactions").then(result => {
            const response = result.data;
            this.setState({ transactions: response, loading: false });
        }).catch((error) => {
            // Error
            if (error.response) {
                // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
                // that falls out of the range of 2xx
                console.log("ERROR RESPONSE DATA : " + error.response.data);
                console.log("ERROR RESPONSE STATUS : " + error.response.status);
                console.log("ERROR RESPONSE HEADERS : " + error.response.headers);
            } else if (error.request) {
                // The request was made but no response was received
                // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the 
                // browser and an instance of
                // http.ClientRequest in node.js
                console.log(error.request);
            } else {
                // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
                console.log('Error', error.message);
            }
            console.log(error.config);
        });
```